# Updating deprecated AWS Amplify setup with the latest Amplify setup

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

my current Android project, which was just handed over to me, used a depricated AWS Amplify setup. I found this documentation and checked it against the code.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-android-app-with-aws-amplify-part-1/

It says that *"This post has been deprecated. Instead, please see the new Amplify Android Getting Started tutorial to learn how to build Android mobile applications using AWS Amplify."* and instead points me to this. https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/android

Can you point me to the right direction on how can I safely migrate the old AWS Amplify setup of my Android project to the new setup.

Thank you!

By the way I am using Android Studio.